# Design Automation for Inventor. Export to SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am making a [configurator](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/tree/master/AppBundles/CreateSVFPlugin) that uses various Add-in's in Inventor to perform tasks: Change parameters, Export IDW to PDF and I would need to Export from Inventor to SVF format (So as not to have to do it with Model Derivate)

I have seen the example of [forge-configurator-inventor](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-configurator-inventor/tree/master/AppBundles) that contains the AppBunle "CreateSvfAutomation", but I don't really understand why it saves the file `"bubble.json"` instead of `"result.svf"`. And what do we do with this `"bubble.json"` file and how can we indicate to our Web viewer the URL to show the SVF

Answer (score 0):

It's a manifest describing the SVF structure. This [article](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/speed-viewable-generation-when-using-design-automation-inventor) may help explain it in a simpler context.